# Can a Live Telecast Be Edited?

Tags: editing, wwe

Just curious to know whether the Live telecast can be edited before they are actually broadcast in TV Channels? Some famous shows like [WWE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5c60GgYIWw) are alleged to have displayed the shows after editing.

Just need some experts info regarding editing of Live shows and if yes, how this can be edited within a few seconds delay?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[As per the Wikipedia article for Live Television](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_television):

> The unedited nature of live television can pose problems for
>   television networks because of the potential for mishaps. To enforce
>   the Federal Communications Commission (FCC) regulations, television
>   networks often broadcast live programs on a slight broadcast delay to
>   give them the ability to censor words and images while keeping the
>   broadcast as "live" as possible.